# xUnit.net IsType Equivalent in MS Test That Returns Type

Tags: c#, mstest, xunit.net

I'm following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-1.1#comments-container) and I'm trying to write a similar test with MS Test.  Does MS Test have an [`IsType()`](https://github.com/xunit/assert.xunit/blob/master/TypeAsserts.cs#L73) that **returns the object** when the cast is successful?

From [this comparison](https://xunit.github.io/docs/comparisons), I see I can use `IsInstanceOfType()` but the return type is `void`.

---

I'm trying to implement this line in MS Test: 
`var badRequestResult = Assert.IsType<BadRequestObjectResult>(result);`

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task IndexPost_ReturnsBadRequestResult_WhenModelStateIsInvalid()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockRepo = new Mock<IBrainstormSessionRepository>();
    mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.ListAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult(GetTestSessions()));
    var controller = new HomeController(mockRepo.Object);
    controller.ModelState.AddModelError("SessionName", "Required");
    var newSession = new HomeController.NewSessionModel();

    // Act
    var result = await controller.Index(newSession);

    // Assert
    var badRequestResult = Assert.IsType<BadRequestObjectResult>(result);
    Assert.IsType<SerializableError>(badRequestResult.Value);
}
```

---

Yes, I could cast using `as` and then use `IsInstanceOfType`...  just wondering if there is a one-liner.

```cs
var badRequestResult = result as BadRequestObjectResult;
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(badRequestResult, typeof(BadRequestObjectResult));
```

---

Reference: [Add to MSTest Request](https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/413)

Comment: There is no equivalent version in MSTest that I have ever come across

Comment: also if casting then there is no need to check if instance is of type. just check if it is not null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no equivalent version in MSTest that I have ever come across.

also if casting, then there is no need to check if instance is of type. Just check if it is not null.

```
// Act
var result = await controller.Index(newSession);

// Assert
var badRequestResult = result as BadRequestObjectResult;
Assert.IsNotNull(badRequestResult, "Expected BadRequestObjectResult");
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(badRequestResult.Value, typeof(SerializableError));
```

Otherwise, you can create your own assertion

```
public static class AssertExtension {
    public static TExpected AssertIsType<TExpected>(this object actual, string message = null) 
        where TExpected : class {
        TExpected result = actual as TExpected;
        Assert.IsNotNull(result, message);
        return result;
    }
}
```

that provides the desired behavior

```
// Assert
var badRequestResult = result.AssertIsType<BadRequestObjectResult>();
badRequestResult.Value.AssertIsType<SerializableError>();
```